# Issue retrieving JSON in Android

Tags: java, android, json

I've looked at countless projects and tutorials and haven't been able to figure out why my app is crashing as soon as it is ran.  It seems to run fine if i comment out the first line in the  try catch "JSONObject dataObject = json.getJSONObject("data");"  The JSON that i'm trying to parse is formatted as such:

```
    {"recordcount":3,
 "columnlist":"department,emailaddress,firstname,has_photos,job_full_title,job_title,kid,lastname,location,middlename,no_show_photo,phone,school",
 "data":
 {"department":["Public Safety","Information Technology","Information Technology"],
 "emailaddress":["todd.mongeon@wne.edu","amutti@wne.edu","fatemeh.shams@wne.edu"],
 "firstname":["Todd","Tony","Toffee"],
 "has_photos":["Y","Y","N"],
 "job_full_title":["Officer","Director, Administrative Information Systems","Sr.Technical Programmer/Analyst and Integ Specialist"],
 "job_title":["Officer","Director, Administrative Information Systems","Sr.Technical Programmer/Analyst and Integ Specialist"],
 "kid":[286899,2497,297411],
 "lastname":["Mongeon","Mutti","Shams"],
 "location":["PS","12 V","12 V"],
 "middlename":["A.","M.",""],
 "no_show_photo":["","",""],
 "phone":["413-782-1207","413-782-1212","413-796-2398"],
 "school":["Public Safety Group","Information Technology Group","Information Technology Group"]}}
```

My program looks like this (please excuse formatting / things that don't need to be there... it needs to be cleaned up from a lot of the things i've tried to get this to work..)

```
    public class Directory_finalActivity extends ListActivity {

public static String url = "http://www1.wne.edu/webservices/directorydemo.cfc?wsdl&method=getEmployees&limit=25&firstname=to&outputtype=JSON";

// JSON array names
private static final String TAG_FIRST = "firstname";
private static final String TAG_LAST = "lastname";
private static final String TAG_SCHOOL = "school";
private static final String TAG_DEPARTMENT = "department";
private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "emailaddress";
private static final String TAG_PHONE = "phone";
private static final String TAG_JOB = "job_title";
private static final String TAG_LOCATION = "location";




//create JSON array
JSONArray firstNames = null;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    // Creating JSON Parser instance
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();        
    // getting JSON string from URL
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);


    String[] firstNames = null;
    try {
        // Getting the data object
        JSONObject dataObject = json.getJSONObject("data");  //This is the line that seems to be causing the error.
        int numResults = json.getInt("recordcount");
        /**
        JSONArray firstNameArray =  dataObject.getJSONArray("firstname");
        JSONArray lastNameArray =  dataObject.getJSONArray("lastname");
        JSONArray schoolArray =  dataObject.getJSONArray("school");
        JSONArray departmentArray =  dataObject.getJSONArray("department");
        JSONArray eMailArray = dataObject.getJSONArray("emailaddress");
        JSONArray phoneNumberArray = dataObject.getJSONArray("phone");
        JSONArray jobTitleArray = dataObject.getJSONArray("job_title");
        JSONArray locationArray = dataObject.getJSONArray("location");
        //Loop through index of array(s)
        for(int i = 0; i <= numResults; i++)
        {   
            //Store value of JSONArray at index "i" into string variables.
            String firstName = firstNameArray.getString(i);
            String eMail = eMailArray.getString(i);
            String phone = phoneNumberArray.getString(i);

            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(TAG_FIRST, firstName);
            map.put(TAG_EMAIL, eMail);
            map.put(TAG_PHONE, phone);

            //add the hashmap to array list.
            contactList.add(map);
        }*/
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    /**
     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
     * */
    //ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, contactList,
    //      R.layout.list_item,
    //      new String[] { TAG_FIRST, TAG_EMAIL, TAG_PHONE }, new int[] {
    //              R.id.name, R.id.email, R.id.mobile });

    //setListAdapter(adapter);



}
```

}

My JSONParser class
    public class JSONParser {

```
static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
```

}

I'm probably doing something incredibly stupid here, i'm new to this so give me a break please haha.  I appreciate any info that you guys may have for me.

For curiosity sake the end goal is to search the database (first name, last name, school, and department) and put the results into a list view, when clicked on a window will pop up displaying other relevant information with a couple other features.

It seems every example i see the JSON output they receive from the url is formatted much differently, so i'm having trouble getting this done even with the amount of examples available (sorry for re-post).
Once again thank you for any assistance.

EDIT 1:
LOGCAT:

```
 04-17 00:45:35.828: W/System.err(305): java.net.UnknownHostException:     api.androidhive.info
04-17 00:45:35.828: W/System.err(305):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:513)
04-17 00:45:35.838: W/System.err(305):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:278)
04-17 00:45:35.838: W/System.err(305):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:242)
04-17 00:45:35.838: W/System.err(305):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:136)
04-17 00:45:35.838: W/System.err(305):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
04-17 00:45:35.838: W/System.err(305):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
04-17 00:45:35.838: W/System.err(305):  at    org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:348)
04-17 00:45:35.838: W/System.err(305):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
04-17 00:45:35.838: W/System.err(305):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
04-17 00:45:35.838: W/System.err(305):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
04-17 00:45:35.838: W/System.err(305):  at directory.plus.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:39)
04-17 00:45:35.838: W/System.err(305):  at directory.plus.Directory_finalActivity.onCreate(Directory_finalActivity.java:53)
04-17 00:45:35.849: W/System.err(305):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-17 00:45:35.849: W/System.err(305):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
04-17 00:45:35.849: W/System.err(305):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-17 00:45:35.849: W/System.err(305):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-17 00:45:35.849: W/System.err(305):  at     android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-17 00:45:35.849: W/System.err(305):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-17 00:45:35.849: W/System.err(305):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-17 00:45:35.849: W/System.err(305):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-17 00:45:35.849: W/System.err(305):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-17 00:45:35.849: W/System.err(305):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-17 00:45:35.858: W/System.err(305):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-17 00:45:35.858: W/System.err(305):  at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-17 00:45:35.858: W/System.err(305):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-17 00:45:35.858: E/Buffer Error(305): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
04-17 00:45:35.868: E/JSON Parser(305): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
04-17 00:45:35.868: D/AndroidRuntime(305): Shutting down VM
04-17 00:45:35.868: W/dalvikvm(305): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
04-17 00:45:35.888: E/AndroidRuntime(305): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-17 00:45:35.888: E/AndroidRuntime(305): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{directory.plus/directory.plus.Directory_finalActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-17 00:45:35.888: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
04-17 00:45:35.888: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-17 00:45:35.888: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-17 00:45:35.888: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-17 00:45:35.888: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-17 00:45:35.888: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-17 00:45:35.888: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-17 00:45:35.888: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-17 00:45:35.888: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-17 00:45:35.888: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-17 00:45:35.888: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-17 00:45:35.888: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-17 00:45:35.888: E/AndroidRuntime(305): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-17 00:45:35.888: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at directory.plus.Directory_finalActivity.onCreate(Directory_finalActivity.java:59)
04-17 00:45:35.888: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-17 00:45:35.888: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
```

EDIT 2:
NEW LOGCAT OUTPUT:

```
04-17 01:26:12.899: E/JSON Parser(548): Error parsing data in JSONParser org.json.JSONException: Value <wddxPacket of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
04-17 01:26:12.899: D/AndroidRuntime(548): Shutting down VM
04-17 01:26:12.899: W/dalvikvm(548): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
04-17 01:26:12.919: E/AndroidRuntime(548): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-17 01:26:12.919: E/AndroidRuntime(548): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{directory.plus/directory.plus.Directory_finalActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-17 01:26:12.919: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
04-17 01:26:12.919: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-17 01:26:12.919: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-17 01:26:12.919: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-17 01:26:12.919: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-17 01:26:12.919: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-17 01:26:12.919: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-17 01:26:12.919: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-17 01:26:12.919: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-17 01:26:12.919: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-17 01:26:12.919: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-17 01:26:12.919: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-17 01:26:12.919: E/AndroidRuntime(548): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-17 01:26:12.919: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at directory.plus.Directory_finalActivity.onCreate(Directory_finalActivity.java:59)
04-17 01:26:12.919: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-17 01:26:12.919: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
04-17 01:26:12.919: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  ... 11 more
04-17 01:26:33.279: I/Process(548): Sending signal. PID: 548 SIG: 9
```

EDIT FINAL: Problem solved:
Needed to take a sub string of the result returned from the html and pass that into a json object

Comment: Have you seen GSON from Google? It takes the pain out of manual JSON parsing http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Comment: @GrahamSmith The OP is not manually parsing JSON, they're using `JsonObject`

Comment: @OP Can you paste your LogCat crash? I recently built JSON parsing almost exactly the same, so I think I might be able to help.

Comment: Just my opinion but you miiiight want to remove all real, relevant information from your post. e.g. email addresses, names, etc.

Comment: FYI, I just pasted your JSON into an online validator (http://jsonlint.com/), and it looks to be valid.  So that's good!

Comment: @Phix, it's all public information that one could obtain at the university website.  And yes I will edit the main post with my logcat asap.

Comment: @DanJ i appreciate the effort, i've used a few validaters & pretty printers in order to validate / make sense of the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > java.net.UnknownHostException:     api.androidhive.info

It looks like your app can't access the network. Have you added:

`<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

to your code AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: I did not have that line and that seems to have fixed the current error.  Now I am getting

    04-17 01:20:20.589: E/JSON Parser(472): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <wddxPacket of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: Requested the URL: "http://www1.wne.edu/webservices/directorydemo.cfc?wsdl&method=getEmployees&limit=25&firstname=to&outputtype=JSON"

It looks like that data contains the following string at the start: `<wddxPacketversion='1.0'><header/><data><string>`

You'll have to remove that at the start and end of the response in order for the JSON library to be able to parse it.

Comment: It suddenly all makes sense!  Thank you very much!  Any recommendations as to how to do this?  Currently just thinking of taking the substring of json.substring(49,json.length()-29)

Comment: Ideally, you could fix it on the server side to just send the JSON part of the response.

If you don't have control over the server, removing the substrings is probably the simplest alternative unless you want to bring in an XML parser as well.

Comment: Awesome, it works very well now via that method.  I greatly appreciate your help!